# mySQL syntax not working

Tags: mysql

Using a try-catch phrase I catch an error in the following code:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from 'user_tbl' where user_id = '"+user+"' ");
```

The error details are as follows:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user_tbl' where user_id = '12345678'' at line 1
```

Is there anything wrong with my syntax here? I'm using Netbeans as my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes are not required, try this:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user_tbl where user_id = " + user);
```

<sub>If user_id is non-integer then enclose `user` variable in single quotes</sub>

Comment: Glad to see a Karachite with 10k+ reputation :)

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo thanks :) i think there are few others as well

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have user_tbl inside ' marks, try removing them so it reads:

`ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
"select * from user_tbl where user_id = '"+user+"' ");`